# What exactly does Guzzle getTransferTime() measure?

Tags: php, guzzle

Guzzle supports returning "transfer time" via `getTransferTime()` on a request.  The [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#on-stats) indirectly mentions that "Included in the [request] data is the total amount of time taken to send the request."  I'm assuming that's what they mean by "transfer time", because there is no other definition.

Now, does this not really indicate the amount of time it takes to receive the response?  Why would anyone want to measure the amount of time it takes to send a request?  What does that even mean?  Is there really a significant amount of preparation that goes into a request?

Comment: The time it takes you to send the request is the minimum time it'll take the server to understand that you're trying to communicate with it. Now you know that if the transfer time is fast but the response time is slow this indicates that the _server_ is taking a while to respond. You can essentially test whether it's a problem with your link to the server being slow or simply the server itself responding slowly.

Comment: The strange thing about this is... the transfer time is usually nearly identical to the response time.  Is there a way to get the response time also from Guzzle, so I can test in the same context?

Comment: Hmm it might seem that I'm wrong and the only info you can get is transfer time and even that seems _estimated_ at best according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the `\GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory` for instance:

```
private static function invokeStats(EasyHandle $easy)
{
    $curlStats = curl_getinfo($easy->handle);
    $stats = new TransferStats(
        $easy->request,
        $easy->response,
        $curlStats['total_time'],
        $easy->errno,
        $curlStats
    );
    call_user_func($easy->options['on_stats'], $stats);
}
```

It correspond to the `total_time` of curl, wich is described as:

> time_total The total time, in seconds, that the full operation lasted.

So it's the whole time: sending the request, waiting for response, getting the response.

In the `\GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler`, you can see that a timer is started before sending the request, and stopped when the response is received.